# How to disable sound on Jlink

Tags: segger-jlink

My JLink is connected to a hub which I connect my laptop. I am often connecting/disconnecting and each time the JLink beeps. This notification is not useful for me.

How do I disable the sound on my JLink?

Answer (score 1):

J-Link does not have an internal speaker and should not make any sounds during connect/disconnect.

Maybe you are referring to the Windows "Device Connect/Disconnect" sound?
It can be changed/disabled in Sound -> tab "Sounds" -> section "Program Events" -> node "Windows" -> child node "Device Connect"

Comment: I have a mac, but that might be it.